# Hive Table Load the Data From Hdfs Location with handled Duplicate Files

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

There is scenario if daily files loading particular path of HDFS location. on top of that path we have created Hive external table to load the data into table in hive. there is worst scenario the files pushed to particular path(HDFS) two times or duplicate files.

How do we load second files instead of doing delete or other job running. what is the best practice to handle this scenario.

Kindly clarify

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated files with similar filanames are not possible in HDFS. If you worry about two files with possible similar content, you might want to load it as is to avoid missing data and maintain a managed table that handles the duplicates.

**Use case: Get only latest file**

Detect latest file from HDFS directory:

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /your/hdfs/dir/ | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3`

Then, move it to another HDFS directory. This directory should be emptied because we want latest file only.

```
# delete old files in here
hdfs dfs -rm -r /your/hdfs/latest_dir/ 
# copy latest file 
hdfs dfs -cp $(hadoop fs -ls -R /your/hdfs/dir/ | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3) /your/hdfs/latest_dir/
```

Comment: how we can avoid missing data, i am not clear. if not possible similar files in hdfs, i want to load second file. what is the solution. please help me.

Comment: partition based or overwrite we can handle this issues right?

Comment: Oh this actually depends on your use case. How often do you receive data? Do you need to keep all data? Do you only need to save the latest file?

Comment: latest file one use case and another one use case to keep all the data both separate solution

Comment: I'll update my answer to include getting the latest file and hope it works for you. Basically you need to create another HDFS folder where you keep only the latest file.

Comment: For the usecase: keeping all data in the table, does keeping all data in directory work? What is the main problem with this usecase?